# React Native Firestore - Get field values

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save my field values into a local array.
`Example:`
[image]
I will get `["84724302","60855802"]`
And by the way the field name is not `0` & `1`.

When I'm trying to do it with documentSnapshot.data() it returns this result:
`[{"field_name": "84724302", "field_name": "60855802"}]`
But I need to get this result: `["84724302","60855802"]`

Comment: Can you please tell more details on what was issue?

Comment: I have document with some fields. I want to save them into an array without the field name (only the value). How to do it?
When I'm trying to do it with documentSnapshot.data() it saves the field name too.
So it will show: `["field_name": "84724302", .....]`

Comment: What you typed there in that comment is not valid JSON, so it can't be stored in a Firestore document. It's probably more likely that we can help if you edit your question to show the code that you tried that is not giving the result that you want.

Comment: My fault, This is what i've got: `[{"field_name":"84724302", ....}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert the object that you are getting to an array

```
firestore.collection('collection').doc('123').onSnapshot(doc=>{
  const arr=Object.values(doc.data())
 console.log(arr) // ["84724302","60855802"]
//...
})
```